# Replace GitHub tokens in an external file

Tags: github-actions

Is there a way to replace GitHub Actions secrets & env vars in an external file - easily.

I have a file in my repo - contents:

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: thingo-service
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/test/test/hello-world:${{env.tag}}
        ports:
          - name: http1
            containerPort: 5000
        env:
          - name: secret_x
            value: ${{ secrets.SECRET_X }}
         - name: secret_y
            value: ${{ secrets.SECRET_Y }}
```

I need to replace those tokens and pass this file as parameter into another Github Actions step.

In other CI/CD systems such as Octopus deploy you can name files to apply transformation logic to, is there a similar Action available to do this?

Cheers

Comment: What is "another process"? Make it clear or this question cannot be answered.

Comment: Sorry, another step.

Comment: That's still far from "clear". In GitHub Actions terms, do you mean "another workflow in the same repo"? Since secrets and environments are saved for the whole repo, another workflow in the same repo can access directly without "passing this file".

Comment: There is an additional action - specifically deploy to GCP Cloud Run that requires a parameter file. I need to transform some secrets in that file. I have a solution using EOT and cat inline but it's not very elegant. I was wondering if there is a way to instruct GHA to scan a particular file and transform tokens in it. You can do this in other CI tools.

Comment: So in which way did you deploy to GCP Cloud Run? I don't think "a parameter file" is ever required if you use templated actions like [this](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun). They work well with secrets you stored in the repo, so you don't ever need a transformation to reveal the token explicitly.

Comment: I need to change the container port number, which is not supported via the Actions arguments explicitly, so I have to use the metadata argument and a YAML file. If you look here: https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun/blob/main/src/deploy-cloudrun.ts#L105  you will see that in this case the env vars argument is subsequently ignored, therefore I need to transform them into the manifest manually. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: If secrets can be accessed in a shell script, I think you can generate any file as you like, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68435485/is-it-possible-to-use-github-secrets-inside-my-shell-file